# Stripping and/or altering the content of a custom field (video URL)

Tags: custom-field, functions

I’m making a theme where some posts have an associated video, from either Vimeo or YouTube. At the moment, users can add this to a post by adding a video ID into one of two custom fields, called (surprisingly enough), 'YouTube' and 'Vimeo'. My theme then takes this info and adds it to the standard embed code for these sites, and outputs it on the post page.

However, I’d like to make things easier for the users of the site, if possible. I’d like to replace these two fields with a single custom field, and also allow them to enter the full URL of the video on Vimeo or YouTube (instead of the ID).

I presume that this would require two things: firstly, that the URL is recognised as coming from either Vimeo or YouTube, and secondly, that the rest of the URL is stripped, so that I can use the ID to output the embedded video nice and clean on post pages.

I know that there are plenty of plugins that do this kind of thing (and other similar things) automatically, but I’d prefer to have this built-in, if at all possible.

I’m not a PHP wizard so I haven’t ventured into doing anything about it yet, but I’m hoping that this could be made to happen via some functions.php magic.

Anyone have any ideas about the best way to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whipped up a nifty little parsing function for you:

```
function wpse44048_parse_video_link( $link ) {
    $url = 'some url'; // pass this in
    $parsed_url = parse_url( $url );

    $host = $parsed_url['host'];

    // check that the service exists, otherwise return false
    if( strpos( $host, 'youtube.com' ) !== false
     && strpos( $host, 'youtu.be' ) !== false
     && strpos( $host, 'vimeo.com' ) !== false ) {
         return false;
    }

    // set $service
    if( strpos( $host, 'youtube.com' ) !== false
     || strpos( $host, 'youtu.be' ) !== false ) {
        $service = 'youtube';
    }
    if( strpos( $host, 'vimeo.com' ) !== false ) {
        // handle vimeo
        $service = 'vimeo';
    }

    // set $video_id
    if( strpos( $host, 'youtube.com' ) !== false ) {
        // handle youtube regular url
        $vars = array();

        parse_str( $parsed_url['query'], $vars );

        $video_id = $vars['v'];
    }
    if( strpos( $host, 'youtu.be' ) !== false ) {
        // handle youtube shortened URL
        $video_id = $parsed_url['path'];
    }
    if( strpos( $host, 'vimeo.com' ) !== false ) {
        // handle vimeo
        $video_id = $parsed_url['path'];
    }

    return array(
        'service' => $service, // youtube or vimeo
        'id'      => $video_id // the id of the video
    );
}
```

No testing done on that, but I based it on [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id). The function is expansible, though you may want to rewrite it. I wrote it to use a centralized value for the services so `youtube.com` and `youtu.be` links wouldn't return a different `service` if you changed them, but you could definitely do existence check, set `$service`, and set the `$video_id` all in one `if`, `elseif`, `else` group. General concept is there for you though.

Comment: Hi m0r7if3r, thanks for that. Like I said, I’m a PHP klutz, so I’m not sure I really understand what you’ve given me here, but I’ll go try it out and report back. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Which part of it is unclear?

Comment: Hi m0r7if3r. The problem is not that any of it is unclear. The problem is that I am a front-end designer, mainly working with CSS. So, for me, PHP can get pretty mysterious pretty fast.

If I put your script in functions.php, how do I then get it to output the ID in single.php?

Thanks again.

Comment: If you execute `wpse44048_parse_video_link()` (with the link, naturally) it will return an array that contains `service` and `id`. `id` should be the ID of the video. `service` will be either youtube or vimeo so that you can feed it to the right API code.

Comment: Thanks again. This might be an obvious/noob-ish follow-up question, but can you tell me how I would pass in the link?

Comment: `$_POST` var probably...however you did it before will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks again. At the moment, in single.php, I have this: `<?php if ((get_post_meta($post->ID, "Video", true))) { ?> (begin embed code stuff) <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Video', true); ?> (finish embed code stuff) <?php } ?>`. I’m not sure how I pass this in to your function, and then back out again. Apologies if I’m missing something basic. I’ve been copying and pasting bits of PHP from various places (yes, total cargo-cult coding) so it's not immediately obvious to me how I should go about doing this.

Comment: Or, to put it another way: I think you’ve done the hard part – I just need to figure out the easy part! :)

Comment: it looks like you're using `get_post_meta()` to get your data in that case.

Comment: Hi m0r7if3r. Thanks again. However, I don’t know what that means, or what step to take next as a result. If you want to take a go at explaining in layman’s terms, I’d be very grateful.

Comment: When you're doing `begin embed code stuff`, there's probably a call to `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Video', true )`, where it's stored to a variable. I'm going to call that var `$video_url`. If you pass `$video_url` into `wpse44048_parse_video_link()` as so: `wpse44048_parse_video_link( $video_url )`, you can store the output in a var. I'll call this `$vid_info`. You can then check with `if` statements what `$vid_info['service']` contains and use that to pass `$vid_info['id']` to the correct API (namely vimeo or youtube).

Comment: Hi m0r7if3r. I’m truly grateful for your help. However, it’s still something that’s happening at a level that I have almost zero experience with. I understand that this is probably irritating, but I can’t do anything with what’s in this answer without having the basics cleared up for me. I think I’ll need to start another question here to answer the basics I need in order to then use your code. I’ll do that, and then check back in here, hopefully with a better follow-up question to ask you. Thanks again.

Comment: What you really should be doing is going through php basics from something like w3schools. You'll never be able to understand how to implement it if your fundamental understanding of PHP is such that my last post was too complex for you.

Comment: I know that. Oh, absolutely, I know that. Believe me, if I could stop time in its tracks for six months and just go and learn this stuff, I would. Unfortunately I don’t have that luxury right now. Thanks again, and I’ll let you know how I get on.

Comment: @Tom - contrary to popular belief, it doesn't take six months to learn to read PHP.  Please take m0r7if3r's advice and go to w3schools, and read through the "PHP Basics" section.  It'll take you a few hours, and you'll save hundreds more by not scratching your head over basic syntax.  Seriously, it will give you the right vocabulary to ask what you need to ask, and give you a basis for understanding and implementing the answers you get.  2-3 hours, max - not 6 months.  If you won't do it for our sanity, do it for your own!